# dd imaging on adb a failing device not found

Tags: android, linux, dd, adb

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuN1R.png)

As you seen on the picture, i wanna image of my Galaxy S4 I9500 on adb using dd on Linux Mint. The commands I use are as follows:

first `adb shell`
then `adb devices` to list of my device. And the last  `adb shell su -c dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/storage/sdcard1/img.bin` and the terminal says error: device not found.. How can i solve this problem and how can success the imaging my android phone using dd?

Thanks..

Comment: Why are you trying to use dd to image the device?

Comment: How can i image else ?

Comment: bro, you might want to make you intent to " i dont wanna wipe. i wanna phsycal dump of my phone." more apparent near the top of your Q, as it seems most readers are interpreting incorrectly. I would expect `dd` to work as you have tried, but given the error msg, there is either a misspelling in your cmd, or permissions issues that are really at the root of your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you should replace the screen shot with a copy/paste of the relevant information. Use `{}` from the edit screen toolbar on highlighted text to keep the formatting. AND, in the output you do show, I don't see any "list of devices", only a header msg, with an empty space below. Where are you getting `mmcblk0` ? Good luck.

Comment: What does this command give you? adb shell
cat /proc/partitions

Comment: @srayhunter when i command "adb shell cat /proc/partitions" i can see my phones partitions and you can see ss on link [link](http://i.hizliresim.com/E3zga8.png)

Comment: @shellter thanks your your advice. you're right. I should have explain more clearly. But, i added all the commands I use with a ss on my question, and i add again at here. [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TuN1R.png) and also my phone has rooted. Thanks again..

Comment: Check my updated message below. If that does not work, you can try and stream the output from dd over the adb bridge to your computer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try these commands and let me know know if that works:

```
adb shell
su
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/sdcard/system.img
```

Comment: Not bro. i dont wanna wipe. i wanna phsycal dump of my phone. So i need to learn dumping use dd command. How can i dumping my android phone using dd command?

Comment: @bedesten1618 this has been updated to copy the image and not wipe the data.